# Что значит [NAME_MAX] (C++)

Tags: c++, массивы, потоки-данных, g++

Нужно вывести содержимое директории на C++ код уже есть(лентяй нашел готовый),

```
DIR *dfd; //Открывается поток для чтения из директории
struct dirent *dp; //структура данных в которую будут помещаться  вывод из директории
cout << "Path = ";
char filename[NAME_MAX];
cout << "File = ";
char dir[NAME_MAX];//предмет вопроса
    cin >> dir;
    strcpy(filename, dir);//хз
printf("%s\n\n", filename);
dfd=opendir(filename);//Открытие выбранной директории для получения списка папок и файлов 

while( (dp=readdir(dfd)) != NULL ) // пока в поток поступает информации, она(информация выводится на экран)
        printf("%s\n", dp->d_name);

closedir(dfd);
return 0;
```

только мне не понятен один фрагмент

```
char filename[NAME_MAX];
```

Что это за NAME_MAX и что он делает? Вчера начал изучать C++, поэтому простым языко объясните пжлст. Можете приводит аналогии на C# или Java.
И да, код работает как надо!!! Коментарии мои, мог что-то не так понять.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Макрос, равный максимальному размеру пути в вашем окружении. Вернее, обеспечивающий, чтобы после объявления

```
char filename[NAME_MAX];
```

массива `filename` гарантированно хватало для хранения имени любого файла в системе.

Comment: хорошо, догадывался. Спасибо!

Comment: Оно кстати 256 для виндовз :) и не факт что есть в других системах, разумнее делать селектор из дефайнов, чтоб была совместимость между платформами.

Comment: @NewView вроде как в Linux тоже работает